# How could this line possibly lead to a crash?

Tags: iphone

Trouble code:

```
NSDictionary *contactNameDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:item, @"contact", sortName, @"contactSortName", compositeName, @"compositeName", nil];
```

Error:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00004420 objc_msgSend + 24
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x000042a6 CFRetain + 54
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000a9f0 __CFBasicHashStandardRetainValue + 8
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x000054c0 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 100
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00006184 CFBasicHashAddValue + 276
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x00006cfe CFDictionaryCreate + 58
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x00033d7c -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 1456
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x000361bc -[NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:] + 776
    8   iota                            0x0000cb04 -[CorpDirViewController reloadDisplayList] (CorpDirViewController.m:833)
```

Comment: Are any of item, sortName, or compositeName nil?  Objects added to a dictionary must be non-nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps one (or more) of item, sortName or compositeName have gone out of scope and been garbage collected, even though they're non-nil.

Comment: This is certain to be it. One of those three objects is being sent a `retain` and crashing, because it's no longer a valid object.

Comment: How can I eliminate this crash. can I just add retain to all the variables and then after adding to the dictionary release them?

Comment: hey lynn, I could do that but can u tell me if I could toss an if if those variables are already released? I mean what would this behave like  if(released variable == nil) { do alloc dictionary) }

Comment: It's more like `if(variable != nil) { alloc dictionary }`.  If any key is nil, an `NSInvalidArgumentException` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

item, sortName or compositeName is nil

Comment: That wouldn't cause a crash, it would just cause anything after that not to be added, because a nil object terminates the list. A nil key would cause a crash.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, you're right. Correct is that one of them points to already released object or to some random place in memory -> can't be retained.